# How to show static class members of a template in visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a static class member inside a class which gets passed to a templated function

```
template<typename T> foo(T& x)
{
    for(int i=0; i<T::size; i++)
        doSomething();
}
```

How can I get Visual Studio to show the value of T:size in the debugger?

Comment: The quick workaround would be to add `real_type_name::size` watch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find a way to let Visual Studio tell me the information about `T`.  It's reasonable, as the symbol `T` doesn't exists at run time.

However, there is a workaround way - watch the `x.size`. If the function doesn't receive a parameter of the type `T`, you can always create one:

```
#if _DEBUG   
    T* tmp;
#endif
```

and then watch `tmp.size` (or `tmp->size`).

Hope someone can find a real solution.